# gganimate: make points stay several frames before and after

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have a data.frame containing timestamped events of different kinds, geolocated. I know how to plot an animation of each event as a point, hour by hour, with `gganimate` (*). It would be something like:

```
df = data.frame("id"  = runif(500, 1e6, 1e7),
           'lat' = runif(500, 45, 45.1),
           'long'= runif(500, 45, 45.1),
           'datetime'= seq.POSIXt(from=Sys.time(), to=Sys.time()+1e5, length.out=500),
           'hour'=format(seq.POSIXt(from=Sys.time(), to=Sys.time()+1e5, length.out=500), "%H"),
           'event'=paste0("type", rpois(500, 1)))

ggplot(data=df) + 
  aes(x=long, y=lat, color=factor(event)) + 
  geom_point() +
  transition_states(hour, state_length = 1, transition_length = 0)
```

Now I would like to make points "stay" longer on screen, for instance if an event is at 5:00pm, i want it to be displayed on the animation from 2pm until 8pm (3 frames before and after his position, and if possible fade in and out). I don't know how to do that with gganimate, I tried to use `transition_length` but it's making the points "move" and that makes no sense for me!

Thanks,

**(*) Edit**: I thought of adding 6 duplicated rows for each row, and modifying the hour by -1 to +3, but it's a lot heavier and can't deal with fade in/out

```
library(magrittr)

df %<>% mutate(hour = hour + 2) %>% bind_rows(df)
df %<>% mutate(hour = hour + 1) %>% bind_rows(df)
df %<>% mutate(hour = hour - 4) %>% bind_rows(df)
df %<>% mutate(hour = hour %% 24 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transition_components` and specify 3 hours as the enter / exit length for each point.

**Data**:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 50 # 500 in question
df = data.frame(
  id       = runif(n, 1e6, 1e7),
  lat      = runif(n, 45, 45.1),
  long     = runif(n, 45, 45.1),
  datetime = seq.POSIXt(from=Sys.time(), to=Sys.time()+1e5, length.out=n),
  hour     = format(seq.POSIXt(from=Sys.time(), to=Sys.time()+1e5, length.out=n), "%H"),
  event    = paste0("type", rpois(n, 1)))
```

**Code**:

```
df %>%
  mutate(hour = as.numeric(as.character(hour))) %>%

  ggplot() +
  aes(x=long, y=lat, group = id, color=factor(event)) + 

  # I'm using geom_label to indicate the time associated with each
  # point & highlight the transition times before / afterwards.
  # replace with geom_point() as needed
  geom_label(aes(label = as.character(hour))) +
  # geom_point() +

  transition_components(hour, 
                        enter_length = 3, 
                        exit_length = 3) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade() +
  ggtitle("Time: {round(frame_time)}")
```

[image: plot 1]

This approach works with a datetime variable as well:

```
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id, color = factor(event)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = format(datetime, "%H:%M"))) +
  transition_components(datetime,
                        enter_length = as_datetime(hm("3:0")),
                        exit_length = as_datetime(hm("3:0"))) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade() +
  ggtitle("Time: {format(frame_time, '%H:%M')}")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: THanks, that's brilliant, really makes my day. I corrected a little mistake that made all the hour at 3 Minutes, because `%m` was the month not the minute! Interessingly, the rendering takes quite more time than with the basic code in my question

Answer (score 0):

`gganimate` does not appear to be set up to handle leaving points on the plot. I think that you are going to have to go the manual route.

Here is a (slightly kludgy) approach to duplicate the rows including setting the times at which they should display and the offset (to be used for `alpha` to control fade):

```
df_withRange <-
  df %>%
  mutate(hour = parse_number(hour)) %>%
  split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    lapply(-3:3, function(this_time){
      x %>%
        mutate(frame_time = hour + this_time
               , offset = this_time
               , abs_offset = abs(this_time))
    }) %>%
      bind_rows()
  }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(
    frame_time = ifelse(frame_time > 23, frame_time - 24, frame_time)
    , frame_time = ifelse(frame_time < 0, frame_time + 24, frame_time)
  )
```

Then, this code set up the plot:

```
ggplot(data=df_withRange
       , aes(x=long
             , y=lat
             , color=factor(event)
             , alpha = abs_offset
             )) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_states(frame_time) +
  labs(title = 'Hour: {closest_state}') +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(1,0.2))
```

The plot:

[image]

There is still a lot of clean up to do (e.g., the fade levels, etc.), but that should be a start at least